# Problems passing a dictionary to a template in Django

Tags: django, templates, dictionary, html-table

I am having trouble with what seems to be a simple problem:

I want to pass a dictionary to a template, and then have the template render that dictionary on the page. However, when I run the page, the dictionary doesn't show up...

Here's my views page:

```
def display_meta(request):
    values = request.META.items()
    values.sort()
    c = Context(values)
    return render_to_response('meta_data.html', c)
```

And here's my template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<table>
{% for k, v in c %}
<tr><td> {{k}} </td><td> {{v}} </td></tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

I am not sure what is going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to get anything to show up in the template with the c variable?

Comment: `context` isn't 2nd parameter, 2nd parameter have to be plain dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass context as a dict. You would do so like

```
def display_meta(request):
    values = request.META.items()
    values.sort()
    return render_to_response('meta_data.html', {'c': values})
```

Each key represents the variable that will be available, in this case `c` will be a dict with the items in `values`